# Linking node to multiple nodes(java)

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, linked-list, task

I'm having some trouble with an lab I have to finish. Essentially, the goal of the lab is to create a task network for project management.

Below is a diagram of the network, with each circle representing a task.

[image: task network with task sequences connected]

Furthermore, each task has a few attributes; taskID, taskDuration, earliestStartTime, and latestStartTime. This would therefore need a Task class to store these attributes, as well as any methods.

[image]

Now, I was thinking of creating a LinkedList of Task objects in my Main class. However, I am not sure how I could link one node to several other nodes, as in the diagram above.This is necessary to represent the task flow, as task 3 needs to be completed in parallel with task 4. I understand that this requires some sort of graph implementation, but we are not allowed to use Java's Graph classes, and I am not sure how to implement this myself.

The method I need most help with constructing is the link(Task from, Task to) method. It will be responsible for taking two tasks and connecting them , as in the case of (1,2)/(2,3)/(2,4)/(5,6)/(5,7), etc.

I then need to be able to traverse the entire graph and determine which task are critical and which are not. I the above diagram, the critical ones are bolded. Essentially, these are the tasks that have the same earliestStartTime and latestStartTime.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you to anyone able to help me out!

[image: sample output]

Comment: You can create a class that contains all the required fields and an ArrayList of childTasks, since you apparently can have more than one child. How will you be constructing this graph in code? From left to right?

Comment: essentially in the client program, the user will be able to enter how many tasks will be in the network, as well as the corresponding duration of each task. the user will then be able to enter all of the links they would like between tasks. the program's job is to calculate the earliest and latest start times, and use those to determine if a task is critical or not.

Comment: i have added sample output to the post, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Your base problem can be reduced to implementing a directed, (maybe weighted) graph. In general, there are two possibilities to represent graphs: [Adjacency Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) and [Incidence Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix). Finding nodes on the critical path should be smooth sailing from there on out.

Comment: okay, if i were to implement the adjecency matrix to store the task data, would I make a linked list of Task objects still ? or would you suggest a different data structure?

Comment: @Abhi you can use a two-dimensional array or a linked list. Your call.